# Invalid URL: No host supplied : error while using Request.get(url) in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, get, python-requests

Code:

```
img=requests.get('http:////files.explosm.net/comics/Rob/chainsaw.png')
```

Error Message:

```
requests.exceptions.InvalidURL: Invalid URL u'http://files.explosm.net/comics/Rob/chainsaw.png': No host supplied
```

What's wrong with the url? 
files.explosm.net/comics/Rob/chainsaw.png

Answer (score 13):

You have a few too many '/'s in the URL:

```
img = requests.get('http://files.explosm.net/comics/Rob/chainsaw.png')
```

Hope that helps.